# re-render single child component based on global state change without re-rendering siblings

Tags: reactjs

I have a React parent component with many child components (thousands of SVG elements that are expensive to re-render). The child components display information based on a global state; somewhere is a list of those child components that should be displayed in a special way. Since this list is needed elsewhere, it cannot be local state information in each child, since it is not private to the child.

Following the advice here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html I lifted state up to the parent component. However, only one child changes at a time; for instance the user might click on an SVG element to adjust its display properties (which are stored as props of the child). However, since the state is stored in the parent, calling `setState` on the parent triggers an expensive re-render of the entire parent component, including all its thousands of children, even though most of them haven't changed.

So I'm not sure how to do this properly in React and get good performance. (I've found the `forceUpdate` method, along with many admonitions never to use it.) What I think I want to do is to somehow update the props of a child, but from the documentation, the only way I can see for the parent to update the props of a single child, is for the `render()` method of the parent to be called, which means it is also re-rendering all the siblings that didn't change, and this is the expensive case I want to avoid.

Is there some way for a click handler, stored in the parent or elsewhere with access to the global state, to change this state, and update the props of the single child component that it affected, and then to tell only that child to re-render?

Sorry I'm not including any source code; this is actually written in Dart, not JS, but I assume the issue is at the level of the underlying React library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `shouldComponentUpdate()`, `React.PureComponent` or `React.memo()` (if you are using React > v16.6.0 and functional components). You want something like this:

**Parent Component**

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    color1: "red",
    color2: "blue"
  };

  changeState = () =>
    this.setState((state, props) => ({
      color1: state.color1 === "red" ? "yellow" : "red",
      color2: state.color2
    }));

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Child color={this.state.color1} />
        <Child color={this.state.color2} />
        <button onClick={this.changeState}>Change State</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Parent will toggle the `color1` state property between red and yellow every time `Change State` is clicked. Then, you have some options to optimize your app.

**shouldComponentUpdate()**

```
class Child extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.color !== this.props.color) return true;
    return false;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.color }}>I am a child</div>
    );
  }
}
```

**React.PureComponent**

```
class PureComponentChild extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.color }}>I am a child</div>
    );
  }
}
```

**React.memo()**

```
const FunctionalChild = React.memo(props =>
  <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.color }}>I am a child</div>
);
```

For more info, take a look at [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) and [React.memo()](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#reactmemo)

Comment: Thanks! Only the first is available to me since it appears the Dart react package uses React version 15. I set up 40,000 child components to compare the times. Without the optimization it takes about 6 seconds to re-render the whole parent, and with the optimization it takes about 3 seconds. So there's still a slowdown, presumably due to executing a loop for 40,000 iterations calling shouldComponentUpdate. I'm still curious if there's a way of doing this that doesn't involve storing the data as a state in the parent, allowing to trigger a re-render of only 1 child and not render the parent.

Comment: lol, you have a good amount of component there mate. Well, you can write a getter in the parent if you really need to keep the state in the Child and still know it in the Parent but **it is not the React way**.

Comment: Just in case you want a direction, it would look like this: **in the Parent:** `getChildState(childState){// do something with child state}` and pass it to the Child: `<Child getChildState={this.getChildState} />`. **In the Child:** call `this.props.getChildState(this.state)` from the constructor or `componentDidMount()` and from the `componentDidUpdate()`. But again, **don't do this unless you have a really good reason to do so**.